# Replace null values per country with the min of a column for that country specifically

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I'm trying to

- step 1.
  Get the min incidence of malaria for each country
- step2
  -If a country has a nan value in the 'IncidenceOfMalaria' column, fill nan values with the minimum value of that column **FOR THAT VERY COUNTRY AND NOT THE MIN VALUE OF THE ENTIRE COLUMN.**

### My attempt

```
malaria_data = pd.read_csv('DatasetAfricaMalaria.csv')
malaria_data["IncidenceOfMalaria"].groupby(malaria_data['CountryName']).min().sort_values()
```

### I get a series like so

[image]

Stuck at this level. How can I proceed or what would you rather have me do differently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be something like this

```
malaria_data.groupby('CountryName')['IncidenceOfMalaria'].apply(lambda gp : gp.fillna(gp.min())
```

Will probably give you what you want, i didnt test it out because there is no sample data but please tell me if an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for attempting the questions. You can get the data set from here https://github.com/carlw0194/Data-Analysis-Projects/blob/main/DatasetAfricaMalaria.csv. Also there return type of code above is a tuple. The desired return type is a series that can be used to substitute an entire column in the data set.

Comment: Why dont you try it again buddy i reedited i am pretty sure nwo is gonna return a series.

Comment: BABOOOYEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE your welcome